# To: complement or telling the purpose

Tags: meaning-in-context, infinitives

> This research contributes to filling a considerable gap in academic literature dissertating on the application of CSR(corporate social responsibility) policies **to address negative publicity.**

Does "to address negative publicity" act as a complement in this context,  if so, I guess it should complement **application**?

But I also understand that **to** tells the purpose, so can the sentence mean that 
"literature dissertates on the application of CSR policies in order to address negative publicity", and the infinitive would be linked to **dissertates**?

Under this context , does the infinitive function as complement or does it tell the purpose?  Or can it be argued that both options are possible?

The entire paragraph is as follow:

> Product or service failure should be seen as a chance for a corporation to prove their efforts and satisfy customers to keep them coming back. This research examines the findings of existing CSR (corporate social responsibility) literature regarding the recovery of corporate brand image supported by the legitimacy theory. Changes in consumers' perceptions are compared between Time0(the time when the negative incident such as food safety scandal occurs) and Time1(a year after). **This research contributes to filling a considerable gap in academic literature dissertating on the application of CSR policies to address negative publicity.** To that end, in this research, consumer behavior is examined in relation to corporate history of CSR implementation.

Comment: Your example sentence makes no sense.  Could you include more of the context, or link to the original source?  Either way, it's just awful writing.

Comment: @Andrew I included the entire paragraph in the post, it's not written by a native English speaker, I was collecting materials for my assignment and came across this thesis.

Comment: Ah I see. It's an abstract of a scientific article. That's why the overly affected language.  "Dissertating" is the main source of confusion as it's not a word, or rather, not the right word. I would have simply said "academic dissertaions".

Comment: Also "contributes to filling" is unnecessarily florid.  Why not just "fills"?

Comment: It's a poorly written piece that is too technical to be clear. Nevertheless, I'm inclined to say that it's an infinitival relative clause modifying "policies".

Comment: @BillJ Does it mean that it would be equivalent to " literature dissertating on the application of CSR policies **that/which** address negative publicity. " ?

Comment: It has a modal meaning comparable to that expressed in finites by "can" or "should": "... the application of CSR policies that can address negative publicity. That assumes it's a relative clause, which I'm not entirely sure about due to the poorly-written sentence.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for the answer. Btw, I wonder if the usage of infinitives in certain contexts can also be difficult for native English speakers to understand? Sometimes I have a hard time understanding whether infinitives are acting as a complement or infinitival relative clause or they express the purpose.

Comment: Infinitival relative clauses are always modifiers, but infinitivals can be complements as in "It provides an opportunity to broaden the mind", where the infinitival is licensed by "opportunity". And infinitivals can be purpose adjuncts, as in "I go to the gym (in order/so as) to keep fit". Generally, it's possible to insert "in order" or "so as" in purpose infinitivals as I've shown.

Comment: Further, the infinitival can't be a complement in your example since "policies" does not license (specifically require or permit) infinitival complements. Remember that infinitival complements in NP structure must be licensed by the noun.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you again, can I say that if the noun's meaning is complete without the infinitive, the infinitive that follows will be infinitival relative clause. And if the meaning of the noun is incomplete, the infinitive that follows will be a complement?

Comment: @Andrew I am not sure if I am allowed to ask, cause this has more to do with the question I asked in the previous post. Even though the example sentence doesn't make much sense, "dissertating on..." will be a participle phrase modifying "literature", is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence is part of the abstract of a scientific article, which helps explains what I would consider overly florid (and somewhat pretentious) verbiage.  Expressions like

> This research **contributes to filling** a considerable gap ...

should be simplified to

> This research **fills** a considerable gap ...

Or, if this sounds too presumptive, then something less assertive like:

> This research **addresses** a considerable gap ...

Meanwhile, "academic literature dissertating on" includes the gerund form of the mostly unused verb "dissertate".  Why not write it with less fanfare?

> academic **dissertations** on ...

For the record, these expressions aren't *incorrect*, but they are *awkward*.  They draw attention to themselves.  When writing scientific articles, you want the reader to think about *what* you are saying, rather than be distracted by *how* you are saying it.

---

With all that out of the way:  Because this sentence is poorly written, it's difficult to say which noun the writer intends "to address negative publicity" to complement.  As written, the preposition "to" suggests the phrase defines *why*, not *what*, and so logically seems to fit more with "applications".  To paraphrase:

> ... applications (of some sort) **for the purpose of** addressing negative publicity.

However it's possible the writer intends the phrase to complement the "policies" that companies *apply*.  If this is true, I would have written:

> CSR policies **that** address negative publicity.

Again, since we're dealing with a writer who seems to think *grandiloquence* is more important than *clarity*, it's hard to say which is true.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, one question that still confuses me is that whether the author is intending the gerund form "dissertating" to be participle that modifies "academic literature" .

Comment: I disagree with the first part of this answer. This research is _intended_ to do (something). Only the reader/wider community can say whether or not if fills the gap that was identified, so it would be premature of the author to state as a fact, in a scientific document, that it did. This style of writing is normal for an academic context.

Comment: @MikeBrockington  That's fair.  If "fills" is too presumptive, then how about, *"This research **addresses** a gap"*?    The point is that this synopsis could use a good editor.

Comment: I think we both agree that this passage is a long way away from 'normal conversational English', so is not a good template for learning anything other than how to write an academic paper, but in that regard the only thing that is really wrong with it is the use of 'dissertating'.  My choice would actually be: "this research _attempts_ to ..."

Answer (score 1):

> Does "to address negative publicity" act as a complement in this
>   context, if so, I guess it should complement application?

No, it acts as a complement to "CSR ... Policies".

Comment: Given this sentence is very poorly written, and so difficult to know exactly what the writer is trying to say, if the phrase really complemented "policies" it should have been written, *"policies **that** address negative publicity"*.  Instead my feeling is that is complements "application"